# python gnupg over ssh works in python shell, not in script

Tags: python, ssh, gnupg

This is a question about a command which works in pythons interactive mode over SSH, but not if included in a script. It is driving me mad. I have been having problems with the script, but now I have discovered that I can simply put the lines into the python shell and I get the exact result I was expecting! This is confusing me, and I don't know how to proceed because I need it to work in a script. For the python shell, I log in via SSH, and then open a python script rather than login via the python ssh module. From there, it works exactly as expected.

```
import ssh
import gnupg
import pickle

s = ssh.Connection(host = 'ipaddress', username = 'toolserv', password = 'xxxx') 

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/toolserv/.gnupg") 

with open("result1.txt", "r") as my_file:
    signed_data1 = pickle.load(my_file)
    my_file.close()

print signed_data1

s.close()
```

If I execute the script as from sudo the error I get from the script is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sshx.py", line 11, in <module>
    with open("result1.txt", "r") as my_file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'result1.txt
```

ls -ld gives the following result: 
    drwxr-xr-x 29 toolserv toolserv 4096 2012-08-19 22:38

Comment: how you launch the script? try this: `sudo python script.py`?

Comment: i just put 'python sshx.py' at the command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Initial answer

Your script is getting executed on your local host, not on your target server. Notice how you open an `SSH` session and then don't use it.

The `toolserv` user likely doesn't exist on this host. Hence the error when `gnupg` tries to create the directory.

### In reaction to your comment:

Let me make this clearer. Merely calling `s = ssh.Connection(host = 'ipaddress', username = 'toolserv', password = 'xxxx')` **does *not* mean** that all subsequent code will be executed on the remote host.

Right now, what you code does is the following:

1. Connect to the remote host at `ipaddress` through SSH
2. Use the gnupg lib with the keys located at `/home/toolserv/.gnupg` on the *local host*.
3. Read some (pickled?) file's content that is on your local host.
4. Print that (unpickled) content
5. Close the SSH connection (without ever using it).

You never use the SSH connection, this is *probably* not what you want and *probably* why your script is failing.

Of course, if you execute the exact same script on your remote host by login in through SSH and then using the shell, your local host is actually the remote host, so it works. However, the fact that the code works when executed from your remote host is **nothing more than an coincidence**.

**One last time, your script probably does not do what you think it does, and unless you investigate that, it's never going to work.**

Comment: apologies, I have edited the question to reflect how i log in. first i ssh through the command line to the toolserv machine. THEN i go into the python shell. now if i launch the script using sudo python sshx.py, it gives a different error message. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yes, thanks. the ssh module i use implements paramiko, so i now realise that i have to load the file through paramiko's built in functins.